# How can fix error adding value to procedure?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I  get the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `string` to `int`

Here is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object 
sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    String Id = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

     try
     {
         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_csData))
         {
             conn.Open();
             SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("updateTable", conn);
             comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

             comm.Parameters.Add("@vrID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Id;

             SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
             da.SelectCommand = comm;
             DataTable db = new DataTable();
             da.Fill(db);

             dataGridView1.DataSource = db;

         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(String.Format("An error occurred: '{0}'", ex.Message));
     }
 }
```

I also tried this:

```
int Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Please post the SP's code.

Comment: the error message is literally telling you what the problem is..

Comment: Could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)

 {


 int Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());

  try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_csData))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("updateTable", conn);
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;



                comm.Parameters.Add("@vrID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Id;

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
                da.SelectCommand = comm;
                DataTable db = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(db);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = db;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("An error occurred: '{0}'", ex.Message));
        }
   }
```